# Is it possible to detect when the user changes the date of an appointment directly from the calendar?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I am writing an outlook web Add-In where the user can create an appointment and book a meeting room through the software.

The problem is that once the user closes the Add-In and goes back to the calendar, they can freely change the date of the appointment by dragging it around, and the Add-In cannot see those changes, since it's not open.

That means that those changes do not get registered into the system and are essentially only local to the user who made them. I need a way that I can detect whenever the user changes the date of an appointment, so that I can update the data on my end.

I have heard about subscribing to notifications but I'm not sure that is the best solution. Any Ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not from a web addin - you can do that from a standalone app that continuously runs and uses either the Outlook Object Model (`Items.ItemChange` event) or EWS to receive the folder notifications. Or you can do that from a COM addin that uses the `Items.ItemChange` event.

Comment: Would that app live inside or outside outlook? If outside, how would I get the right permissions to get calendar notifications from the right users?

Comment: Do you mean inside the outlook.exe process? It really does not matter - COM addins (being dlls) are loaded inside the outlook.exe process when it starts up. For the the out-of-proc access, the COM system marshals all calls to the Outlook Object Model.

Comment: I assume you are looking for a way for addin-backend to know when events gets updated. For this, you can stamp a customer property in the event and subscribe for any changes using Graph APIs. This support link talks about this flow: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4505745/cannot-save-meeting-as-draft-in-outlook-for-mac-using-office-js-api